# How to use a single HttpServletResponse object for performing multiple actions(doPost) on an actionservlet?

Tags: servlets, struts

If i tried to use same HttpServletResponse object for performing more than one action, i am getting an Exception "Response is already committed".
Is there any way of cloning the response before performing actions(calling dopost on actionServlet).
Is it possible to use multiple wrapped responses created on a common response object.

```
wrappedResponse1 = new HttpServletResponseWrapper(response);
wrappedResponse2 = new HttpServletResponseWrapper(response);
wrappedResponse3 = new HttpServletResponseWrapper(response);

actionServlet.doPost(wrappedResponse1);
actionServlet.doPost(wrappedResponse2);
actionServlet.doPost(wrappedResponse3);
```

Will the abobe code work. If not what could be the approach to create multiple responses .

Comment: What is an `actionServlet`?

Comment: what is your use case ?